# Whether Drone support configuring timeout value for build

Tags: drone.io

I setup a local drone server for our CI. And our project is a java project managed by maven. When run the `mvn clean install` command, maven will download all dependencies into `~/.m2` directory. The first time run this command will download a huge of data from maven remote repository which may take a very long time. In this case, I got below error on drone CI.

```
ERROR: terminal inactive for 15m0s, build cancelled
```

I understand that this message means there is no output on the console for 15 minutes. But it is a normal case in my build environment. I wander whether I can configure the 15m to be a larger value so I can build our project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My previous answer is outdated. You can now change the default timeout for each individual repository from the repository settings screen. This setting is only available to system administrators.

---

You can increase the terminal inactive timeout by passing `DRONE_TIMEOUT=<duration>` to each of your agents.

```
docker run -e DRONE_TIMEOUT=15m drone/drone:0.5 agent
```

The timeout value may be any valid Go duration string [1].

```
# 30 minute timeout
DRONE_TIMEOUT=30m

# 1 hour timeout
DRONE_TIMEOUT=1h

# 1 hour, 30 minute timeout
DRONE_TIMEOUT=1h30m
```

[1] https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseDuration

Comment: Is there a way to configure this via the .drone.yml? In other words, at the project level?

Comment: same question, whether we can set it in yml?

Comment: No, this timeout is global.

Comment: I should mention that drone has two different timeouts. There is a per-repository timeout that defaults to 60 minutes, and can be modified in the UI. The timeout mentioned above, however, is a global configuration that kills the build if it doesn't write to the terminal for > 15 minutes. This prevents people from accidentally hanging the build with blocking commands.

Comment: The per-repository timeout isn't for inactivity, right? So, the only way to change the inactivity timeout is with the global setting? I'm the maintainer of github.com/ensime/scala-debugger, which is part of the ensime family. We upgraded drone recently and now I'm hitting the inactivity issue while compiling a lot of code on our slowest machine in our cluster. I wish there was some way for a maintainer of a project (or an admin of drone) to be able to configure the inactivity timeout per project.

Comment: Correct, the per-repository timeout is total duration. The inactive console timeout is a global configuration. To resolve this issue you will therefore need to follow the steps described in my answer above.

Comment: DRONE_TIMEOUT doesn't exist anymore, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the drone source code, it looks like they have environment variables `DRONE_TIMEOUT` and `DRONE_TIMEOUT_INACTIVITY` that you can use to configure the inactivity timeout. I tried putting it in my .drone.yml file and it didn't seem to do anything, so this may only be available at a higher level.

Here is the reference to the environment variable `DRONE_TIMEOUT_INACTIVITY`:
https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/17e5eb50363f3fcdc0a0461162bee93041d600b7/drone/exec.go#L62

Here is the reference to the environment variable `DRONE_TIMEOUT`:
https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/eee4fd1fd2556ac9e4115c746ce785c7364a6f12/drone/agent/agent.go#L95

Here is where the error is thrown:
https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/5abb5de44aa11ea546db1d3846d603eacef7f0d9/agent/agent.go#L206